# Lazyload Angular Modules and components

Tags: angular, components, lazy-loading

I'm working on an Angular 10 app where I need some components taking the full screen view like login and signup which I'm declaring on `app.module` and on the `app.module` I'm lazy loading a module called `user.module` where after login user is redirected and everything should come inside an sidenav and navbar and these two things are set at `HomeComponent`. Now while changing routes I want the `HomeComponent` to remain fix and the rest of the dom should change depending on the route. But while changing routes inside the `user.module` I cannot make the other components load inside the `HomeComponent` and the other components inside user module loads in the space provided by the `HomeComponent` without displaying the `HomeComponent` itselt. Here is my stackblitz project link in case you want to check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-knqrkh?file=src/styles.css.

[image]

app.routing.module.ts

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: 'sign-in', component: SigninComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'sign-in', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'sign-up', component: SignupComponent },
      { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent },
      { path: 'change-password/:userId', component: ChangePasswordComponent },
      { path: '500', component: Error500HandlerComponent },
      {
        path: 'user',
        loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule)
      },
      { path: '**', component: Error404HandlerComponent },
    ];
```

User.routing.module.ts

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'main', component: MainComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'feeds', component: MyFeedsComponent },
  { path: 'friends', component: FriendsComponent },
  { path: 'public', component: PublicComponent }
];
```